# Travelling on Nightjet as a mixed-gender couple

Tags: trains, rome, night-transport, vienna

My partner and I (M+F) are planning to take a Nightjet from Vienna to Rome and we are really confused about the booking options. We are planning to book a sleeper cabin. We are not very fussed about potentially having another person in our compartment, but we do absolutely want to travel in the **same** compartment. The Nightjet website however says:

> Double: Compartment for 2 persons; individual beds are available for
> booking - in this case, you will share the compartment with other
> travellers **(women and men separated)**.
> Triple: Compartment for 3
> persons; individual beds are available for booking - in this case, you
> will share the compartment with other travellers **(women and men
> separated)**.

What does that "women and men separated" mean? Does that mean we would **always** be put in separate compartments unless we book the whole Double compartment for ourselves (the €321.80 option on the screenshot below)?

The booking process doesn't explain this arrangement at all:

[image: booking screenshot]

Comment: There is also the option of booking a couchette compartment for yourselves (it should be explicitly stated in the couchette options, if available). It's not as comfortable, though, but way cheaper than the sleeper.

Answer (score 13):

> Does that mean we would always be put in separate compartments unless we book the whole Double compartment for ourselves (the €321.80 option on the screenshot below)?

Yes. If the number of travellers coincides with the number of beds in the sleeper compartment, whenever possible (which is almost always in my experiences), they will put travellers in the same compartment. Otherwise, the compartments are gender-separated, and it can happen that a bed is sold out for one gender but not the other due to the gender distribution of already sold tickets.

You are welcome to add a fictitious passenger to accompany you to book the three-person compartment for yourselves, but then you have to pay the ticket price for the fictitious passenger; in some rare circumstances, the discount tickets for three could still be cheaper.

If they put you two in one three-person compartment, they cannot sell the other bed to other passengers who are promised a gender-separated compartment. You would be paying two tickets but getting three beds.

Comment: Thank you. I've got the tickets and we were assigned Car number 413, seat number(s) 12, 16. How can I know if 12 and 16 are in the same compartment or not?

Comment: @MikeK As a rule of thumb, beds in the same sleeper compartment start with the same number and end in either even or odd numbers. So 12-14-16 should be in one compartment (14 is omitted in two-bed configurations). Was it a three-person compartment? I will correct the answer if it is.

Comment: We paid for a full compartment, so it should be a 2-person

Comment: Since when are these compartments separated?  I have traveled on night trains in the past and I never encountered such a thing.

Comment: @phoog For nightjet services run by OBB, sleeper cars (but not couchettes) were advertised as single gender (for single travellers) at least since 2017. (https://web.archive.org/web/20171120022042/http://www.nightjet.com/en/ausstattung/reisekategorien/schlafwagen.html)

Comment: You have indeed two beds in the same compartment, which you will have for your exclusive use. You can see the numbering scheme here: 
https://www.seat61.com/reference/trainseatplans/Comfortline-sleeper.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 7):

For future reference, when booking through [nightjet.com](https://www.nightjet.com/en/#/home), there is an explicit option to book an entire compartment.

This is possible for couchettes and seating carriages as well.

[image: booking a sleeper]